# rails_5 select and options_from_collections_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working in rails 5. 
I am working with a database named "meals". Data base "meals" belongs to a database "events". I have the form_for with meals.

```
<%= form_for(meal) do |f| %>
```

I want to a create a drop down with information from database "Events" and then use that as an id for "meals". The dropdown is populated with "events" but i cannot get the event to be selected when I submit the form. 
I am using the "select" combined with "options_from_collection_for_select".

```
</div>
<%= f.select :event_id,  options_from_collection_for_select((events), "id", "name", "events.id" ), prompt: 'select' %>
</div>


Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",  "authenticity_token"=>"9RIvNLt92mYqM5P8m6l3t+vFiNwt/ISzr06pD+0xYlPR+eQR9E9FdsehIn TVwl6U/3q0UHCUw3epaUNuwMvfOw==", "meal"=>{"meal_name"=>"meal", "desc"=>"",   "meal_type"=>"", "event_id"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Meal"}
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  LIMIT ?  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
(0.1ms)  rollback transaction
```

Thank you!

Comment: is event_id in authorized params ?

Comment: If i create a text_field and manually type the event_id then the event id receives a value. However, if i use the drop down, the event_id is not set.